# Linux header and extra modules on ubuntu container from an open suse micro os host with mismatch kernel versions

Tags: ubuntu, kernel-modules, opensuse, linux-headers

I have an Open SUSE micro OS host with kernel `6.5.9-1-default` and an Ubuntu 22.04 distrobox container.

I need to install the `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` and `linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)` packages and the problem is that Ubuntu 22.04 at the time I'm writing doesn't have these packages, their most recent kernel is 6.2.

So, how can I install these Linux headers and modules extra on my Ubuntu 22.04 container?

Comment: What are you trying to do in your container? It would be rather unusual to do anything with modules inside a container...

Comment: @StephenKitt I'm trying to install AMD rocm https://rocm.docs.amd.com/en/latest/deploy/linux/prerequisites.html#kernel-headers-and-development-packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, you’ll need to load your modules into the host kernel, so you need to build them with the host’s configuration exactly. Even finding a matching kernel in your Ubuntu container wouldn’t help, you need the headers matching the host’s kernel and configuration.

I don’t know whether micro OS even supports this, [its web site is currently down for maintenance](https://microos.opensuse.org/).

Comment: I see; I was afraid of that; but it seems I'll need install Ubuntu on host machine. Rocm has support for SUSE Linux Enterprise Server but it is different from MicroOS; Thanks Stephen.